# Time code audio tracks in DAW?

Tags: daw, timecode

How do you generate audio time code (LTC) tracks, if your platform doesn't offer them natively? Some DAWs can generate auxiliary LTC tracks, but many don't.

Audible time code may not be useful right in the session, but it's needed in playout situations such as live venues to drive lighting cues, effects devices, event triggers, sound sync etc.

Comment: Adding a moderator's note here to avoid confusion. This is not spam. Jim's a regular user who saw a problem and came up with a free solution for it. It's a legit question that invites other solutions and he followed proper practice for disclosing his own participation in his proposed solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Various places I've worked have found different solutions. Some record the LTC from a broadcast video tape to an unused track. Some will reuse a track from an earlier project. The first is slow (1:1), and both are inflexible. Hardware TC generators are flexible, but it's still real-time creation.

I offer a free 32-bit Windows utility that can generate an hour or more of SMPTE/EBU code as an audio track (WAV file) in a couple of seconds, at any common frame rate. No catch, it's free for any use, personal or pro. I only ask that you pass along [This Link](http://bit.ly/Esc_TcGen), and not copy/share the program directly. Enjoy, and please send comments or suggestions.